Flask-SocketIO with Blueprint &Name space Issue
Iam New to use falsk-ScocketIo to make chat,i have an issue with  meet events and printing data   and no customer event sent it seam to be an issue for server side I don't Know ,
there are connection  between socit and server as attached image

and  if i need to  print data in terminal or log  no data loged or printed ,i think thre are an issue with Bluebrint or Name space as when i removed Bluprint and code  dirictly it working Fine  i serached more and more and i didnt find solution . here is my code
my socketioController.py :-

    # Import necessary modules and libraries
    from flask import render_template,url_for,flash,redirect,request,Blueprint,request,json,jsonify,session,Response,Flask
    from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
    from myproject import db
    from myproject import app
    from myproject.models import User ,Presentaions,PresntaionImages,PresntaionVideos,Settings,Colors,Hand,PresnterFrameMode,SlidingMode
    from myproject.users.dataValidator import *
    from myproject.handler import *
    import datetime 
    from sqlalchemy import func 
    from sqlalchemy.sql import text
    import cv2
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO, join_room, leave_room, send,emit
    from app import socketio 
 
    
    # Define a Flask Blueprint named 'streaming'
    socketio_blueprint = Blueprint('socketio_blueprint', __name__) 
    # 
    
    @socketio_blueprint.route('/soket/show', methods=['GET','POST'])
    @login_required
    def show():
        pagetitle = "Presenter X | Streaming Details"
        return render_template('socit_template/show.html')
    
    @socketio.on('connect')
    def test_connect():
        print('Client connected')
        emit('custom-event', 'Connected to server!')
    
    @socketio.on('message')
    def handle_message(data):
        print(f'Message received: {data}')
        emit('custom-event', f'Server got your message: {data}')

my html code and Js :-
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flask-SocketIO Test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask-SocketIO WebSocket Test</h1>
    
    <script>
        const socket = io.connect(`${location.protocol}//${document.domain}:${location.port}`);

       

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('WebSocket connected');
            socket.send('Hello, Server!');
        });

        socket.on('custom-event', data => {
            console.log(`Custom event received: ${data}`);
        });
        
        

        socket.on('message', data => {
            console.log(`Message from server: ${data}`);
        });
        
        socket.on('connect_error', (error) => {
            console.error(`Connection error: ${error}`);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

here my  app.py code :-

    from myproject import app
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
    #socketio = SocketIO(app)
    
    
    socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode=None)  # Ensure proper initialization
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        #app.run(debug=True)
        socketio.run(app,debug=True)

 here my init.py code:

    from flask import Flask
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
    from flask_migrate import Migrate
    from flask_login import LoginManager
    import pymysql
    from myproject.config import *
    from flask_mail import Mail
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO
    
    # Initialize the Flask app
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # Configure Mail
    app.config["MAIL_SERVER"] = "smtp.googlemail.com"
    app.config["MAIL_PORT"] = 587
    app.config["MAIL_USE_TLS"] = True
    app.config["MAIL_USERNAME"] = os.environ.get("EMAIL_USER")
    app.config["MAIL_PASSWORD"] = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASS")
    mail = Mail(app)
    
    # Initialize the login manager
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    login_manager.login_view = "users.login"
    login_manager.login_message_category = "info"
    login_manager.login_message = ''
    
    # Initialize database and migrations
    db = SQLAlchemy(app)
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    
    # Initialize SocketIO (ensure it's done after app is created)
    socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*", async_mode=None)
    
    # Import the blueprints AFTER initializing the app, db, and login manager
    from myproject.core.coreController import core
    from myproject.errors.errorhandlers import errors
    from myproject.users.userController import users
    from myproject.setting.settingController import setting
    from myproject.color.colorController import colors
    from myproject.slidingmode.slidingController import slidingmode
    from myproject.hand.handController import hand
    from myproject.presentaion.presentationController import presentation
    from myproject.presnterframemode.presnterframemodeController import presnterframemode
    from myproject.streaming.streamingController import streaming
    from myproject.socketio.socketioController import socketio_blueprint
    
    # Register blueprints
    app.register_blueprint(core)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(colors)
    app.register_blueprint(setting)
    app.register_blueprint(slidingmode)
    app.register_blueprint(hand)
    app.register_blueprint(presnterframemode)
    app.register_blueprint(streaming)
    app.register_blueprint(presentation)
    app.register_blueprint(socketio_blueprint)


it seem to be no reply from server side , i dont Know hopping any one help me may be issue is name sapace .
thanks
